# Do you need React installed for Plotly Dash Python?

Tags: reactjs, plotly-dash

Apparently, Dash in Python is built on top of React using React components for stuff. Does this mean that someone would need npm and React installed, or can they just use Dash components without having npm?

Also, if I have some React code, is there any way to integrate that into Dash without having React and npm be a dependency?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use Dash without installing React or npm. In order to use your own React code in Dash, you'd have to make [custom components](https://dash.plotly.com/plugins). You would need npm for that part, but a machine running Dash code that includes your custom components would not.